# WP CLI method for setting up cron jobs

Tags: cron, cli

I'm having trouble setting up CRON jobs to run on my server (I did read through the various posts on CRON jobs and trouble with CLI but still couldn't find a solution). I've followed the WIKI but can't get past this one error:

Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress install.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.

Here is the code that is erroring:

```
/usr/local/bin/wp --user=myadminusername --url=http://www.mywebsite.org/testfolder/ --path=/home/mywebsite/www/testfolder civicrm api job.execute auth=0
```

I'm pretty confident that this is the absolute path - I checked my civicrm.settings file and this is how it is listed, with the "wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/" appended of course.

Suggestions? I'm newer to CLIs and running CRON jobs so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The syntax looks correct.   Can you execute this via the CLI as opposed to via cron?   Can you change into the website root and complete a wp --info and a 'wp option get home' ?   Just want to make sure wp-cli is working

Comment: There's definitely a chance I don't fully understand cron or WP CLI. I was attempting that command through Terminal on a Mac (after having installed WP CLI). wp --info returns: (PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version: 5.5.30
php.ini used: 
WP-CLI root dir: phar://wp-cli.phar
etc..) I'm not sure my next steps, not afraid of learning just couldn't find related documentation or posts.

Comment: 'wp option get home' give the exact same error so alas something is wrong with wp-cli or how I have it set up.